# TParam.LoadFromStream is not working in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have written a below code in Delphi XE2.

```
var
stream : TStringStream;

begin
stream := TStringStream.Create;

//Some logic to populate stream from memo.

ShowMessage(stream.datastring); //This line is showing correct data

// some Insert query with below parameter setting
ParamByName('Text').LoadFromStream(stream , ftMemo);
```

But this is storing text as ???? in table.

This type of code is working fine in Delphi 4.

Is there any issue in TParam.LoadFromStream function in Delphi XE2?

**EDIT:** 
Table field is of type 'Text'.

Comment: It's clearly an encoding issue, but I'm not sure where the mismatch is. Here are the candidates: 1. TStringString has an Encoding property that defaults to ANSI. You can use ftMemo or ftWideMemo when calling LoadFromStream. The database field has an encoding.

Comment: Same code is working fine with Delphi 4.

Comment: Delphi 4 uses ANSI. XE2 is Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some trial and error methods I have found a solution to this problem.
We can use below code,

```
ParamByName('Text').AsMemo := SampleMemo.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

The root of your issue is that `TStringStream` does not operate the same way in D2009+ as it did in D4.

In D4, `TStringStream` was a simple wrapper around an `AnsiString` variable.  The `DataString` property simply returned a direct reference to that variable, and all reads/writes operated directly on the contents of the variable.  The stream's bytes and String characters were basically one and the same thing back then.

In D2009+, `TStringStream` is now a wrapper around a `TBytes` array of encoded bytes instead, where the default encoding is the default Ansi encoding of the OS that your app is running on.  If you write a string to the stream using `WriteString()`, it gets encoded from Unicode to bytes using the stream's encoding, and then those encoded bytes are stored.  If you read a string from the stream using `ReadString()`, or read the `DataString` property, the stored bytes are decoded to a Unicode string.  Any other read/write operations operate on the raw encoded bytes instead, like any other stream type would.  So when you call `TParam.LoadFromStream()`, it is reading the raw encoded bytes, not a Unicode string.  The stream's raw bytes and String characters are **NOT** one and the same thing anymore.  So the data you see in the `ShowMessage()` is not the same data that `TParam` sees.